# Where is vector WordArt now in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, vector-graphics

In old versions of Word it was possible to create WordArt object and the transform it freely with a mouse. I.e. WordArt object was vector text. Currently it looks not possible: only frame can be modified freely, while text is usual word text with given font and size.

Did the removed old features? Or hided them somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a very detailed article [here](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/classic_wordart_in_word2010_2013_documents.html) from Greg Maxey about using the old style WordArt in new versions of Word.

Basically if you are prepared to save your document as a Word 97-2003 document you can use the old WordArt as it used to be.

Alternatively, if you create the following [macro](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/installing_employing_macros.html) it will add the old style WordArt to a Word file saved in the newer format:

```
Sub ClassicWordArtInsert()
Dim oShp As Word.Shape
Dim oILS as Word.InlineShape
  Set oShp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextEffect(Office.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, _
       "Your Text Here", "Arial", 36, _
       Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0, 0, Selection.Range)
  If MsgBox("Do you want your classic WordArt object inline with text?", _
            vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Classic Inline") = vbYes Then
    Set oILS = oShp.ConvertToInlineShape
  End If
  On Error Resume Next
  oShp.Select
  oILS.Select
  On Error GoTo 0
lbl_Exit:
  Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Copied from aforementioned website.

However, I don't know if this will acheive what you want as you haven't really said what you need to do.